# How do I use quotes in sed within quotes?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, alias, quotes

how do I get this

```
ls -1 | sed 's/\(.*\)/alias \1 "shot \1"/'
```

into an alias?

Example:

```
alias asdf "ls -1 | sed 's/\(.*\)/alias \1 "shot \1"/'"
```

The problem is when I get to the quotes for the alias.

Comment: escaping the quotes with a \ returns Unmatched '.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use aliases, use a function:

```
my_func() {
  ls -1 | sed 's/.*/alias & "shot &"/'
}
```

You should however [avoid parsing the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Please read the link!

In your case, assuming no there is no newlines in the file names, one can use ^0:

```
my_func() {
  printf '%s\n' * | sed 's/\(.*\)/alias \1 "shot \1"/'
}
```

^0 Which leaves you with the same problems parsing ls would, but without without invoking the extra process, as printf is buildin.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
alias asdf="ls -1 | sed 's/.*/alias & \"shot &\"/'"
```

You forgot the assignment operator (`=`); to get double quotes within double quotes, you have to escape them with `\"`.

Also, I've changed your capture group and backreference to using `&`, which stands for the complete match.

Notice that programmatically processing the output of `ls` is [not recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). A robust solution would, for example, use `find` or fileglobs (like [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41188845/3266847)), but the main point of the question is about escaping double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the equal symbol and you must escape double quotes. Try this:

`alias asdf="ls -1 | sed 's/\(.*\)/alias \1 \"shot \1\"/'"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your filenames only contain alphanumerics or DOT or underscore, you should avoid parsing output of `ls`. **Another pitfall is use of pipeline** in your command which will create `alias` only in subshell not in current shell.

You can use this `for` loop instead:

```
for f in *; do
   alias $f="shot $f"
done
```